# how to hide properties of a transaction state based on status

Tags: corda

I have started working on Corda recently. We have got the requirements not to show State properties for specific status. 
 While going through the document I have found some reference below but could not find any suitable example. 
https://solutions.corda.net/corda-modelling-notation/views/views-common-concepts.html

**Properties**

**These are the properties of the State whilst in the particular status. Not all properties need to be shown, just the ones salient to the behaviour of the State in this Status.**

Could you be able to point me to any relevant example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Corda States are available to participants on a need-to-know basis and as a whole. The participant list returned by the `getParticipants()` method of a state defines the participants who should be aware of that state. You could update the participant list (add or remove) to grant or revoke access to a state but it's not possible to grant/revoke access to a part of the state.

To cater to your scenario below possible approaches can be taken:

1. Refactor your entire state into separate states and make them available to parties depending on the status.
2. Handle this on the application layer, after fetching the state from the Corda node and restrict visibility on the basis of the state.
3. Update the state variables to null based on the status, this may not be very feasible but just in case your use-case allows this.